# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter') and console.log = undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm making a post request, I put the variable this.metodo=res, but when I put console.log(this.metodo) or try to use the filter it returns undefined

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cartS.getTransporteMetodo(this.storeS.layout.emp.id).subscribe((res: any[]) => {
  this.metodo = res;

});
    console.log(this.metodo)
  filterMetodos(){
return this.metodo.filter( metodos => metodos.nome  );
 

}
```

the json

```
{
"id": 1,
"emp_id": 1,
"nome": "Retirada na Loja",
"tipo": "RETIRA",
"subtipo": null,
"latLng": [-25.45264, -49.26653],
"vFreteMin": 0,
"vFreteGratis": null,
"periodos": [
  {
    "id": 8,
    "transporte_id": 1,
    "ativo": 1,
    "periodo": "Comercial (das 8h \u00e0s 19h)",
    "corte": "17:00",
    "data": null,
    "week": []
  }
]
```

},

```
  getTransporteMetodo(empId){
return this.http.post(environment.API_URL + 'transporte/getAll', { empId });
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Comment: @R.Richards It helped me to understand, but it didn't work in my code, can you help me with my code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your log inside the the subscribe callback

```
this.cartS.getTransporteMetodo(this.storeS.layout.emp.id).subscribe((res: any[]) => {
  this.metodo = res;
  console.log(this.metodo)
});
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but it didn't return anything in the console

Comment: tried console.log(res) ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't return anything in the console
    this.cartS.getTransporteMetodo(this.storeS.layout.emp.id).subscribe((res) => {

Comment: Are you sure that your call to service is returning values.

Comment: I don't know what to do, I can't see what's wrong in the code

Comment: Try debugging with chrome DevTools

Comment: getTransporteMetodo(empId){
    return this.http.post(environment.API_URL + 'transporte/getAll', { empId });
  }
the request returns in the response

  {
    "id": 1,
    "emp_id": 1,
    "nome": "Retirada na Loja",
    "tipo": "RETIRA",
    "subtipo": null,
    "latLng": [-25.45264, -49.26653],
    "vFreteMin": 0,
    "vFreteGratis": null,
    "periodos": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "transporte_id": 1,
        "ativo": 1,
        "periodo": "Comercial (das 8h \u00e0s 19h)",
        "corte": "17:00",
        "data": null,
        "week": []
      }
    ]
  },

Comment: I'll edit the entire code in the question, can you take a look?

Comment: sure, if possible put it in stackblitz and share the link

Comment: ok, I don't know how to work with stackblitz yet, but I'll try, but I updated the code here too

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nswlaa?file=src/app/app.component.tsI tried to make an example here, I think you can understand

Comment: I can release my remote access for you to take a look if you want (Anydesk)

Answer (score 0):

The reason of getting undefined is that the method is asnyc. So you try to access the variable before being inicialized. If you want to filter the response put the filter into the subscribe method.

sometihng like this:

```
this.cartS.getTransporteMetodo(this.storeS.layout.emp.id).subscribe((res: any[]) => {
        this.metodo = res.filter(item=>nome);   

});
```

Comment: Do you know why console.log is returning undefined?